# How to track logged in user in geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, log

Is there any way I can track the logged in users in geoserver(somewhere in log file). I have same users in geoserver and tomcat-realm.As I can see what URI are requested, IP address URI requested from, time and other info in access log of apache. But I need to find user name who logged in to request those URI.

Thanks

Comment: Can you pass the user.ID variable to the log you're already maintaining? I assume if the instance is running and the user is logged in, their user.ID variable will be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the tomcat configuration file (in conf/server.xml) and add an [AccessLog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Introduction) Valve.

The common log format already logs the username along with url and is *common* in the sense that most log processing tool can process it out of the box.

Comment: I had already added accesslog valve in server.xml file of tomat, but all the time I didn't notice the username was tracked there in access log of tomcat. Thanks a lot guys for the good hints guys.

Comment: Also I would like to add that, I was getting the local apache IP as client IP in tomcat access log, so I modified the server.xml to get the remote client IP using %{X-Forwarded-For}i header in log pattern.
Hope it will be helpful for someone having same issue.

Thanks

Comment: @panalbish for that a better solution is the remoteip valve http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve